# Android Realm ignore field if null

Tags: android, realm

I have a some class "Model"

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;

private Boolean value1;

private Boolean value2;

public Boolean getValue1() {
    return value1;
}

public void setValue1(Boolean value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}

public Boolean getValue2() {
    return value2;
}

public void setValue2(Boolean value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}

public String toString() {
    return "value1 = " + getValue1() + " value2 = " + getValue2();
}
```

and from some API responses some fields maybe NULL, but its correct. What I need: if model from API doesnt contain some field, realm should ignore him, and doesnt save NULL in database. Its possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot "partially merge"  objects. How would Realm know that you actually DO want to set a null field to null?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save some default value instead or just not save any value at all?

Comment: If the API here you mean the JSON response, then yes. If a field doesn't exist in the JSON object, realm will use the default value instead. But before 2.0.0, user cannot set the default value which makes those nullable field `null`. With the default value support in realm-java 2.0.0, you can give a object default values, if the JSON object doesn't have a specific field, the field will be set to the default value you gave when create object. When update object, the field will just be ignored.